# Simplifying circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Can someone help me understand why the circuit has been simplified as seen in the picture?

[image]

Comment: I have seen a post explaining that the 2 vertical resistors were removed because they have the same potential (V1=V3 & V2=V4) and further explained that no current will pass through the 2 vertical resistors that is why they were removed. I am confused about this explanation and hoping someone could thoroughly discuss the reason behind it.

Comment: Google "Wheatstone bridge"

Comment: Thanks for the prompt, kyle! I now get that in a whetstone bridge, when the circuit is balanced, the resistor in between can be removed. However, a wheastone bridge has a 4-arm or a 4 resistors placed in the network. I wanted to ask if the circuit i posted has more resistors compared to a wheatstone, can it still be treated as a wheatstone bridge. To be honest, I am confused with the given circuit that is why I can't visualize it to be a wheatstone.

Comment: @blnkr Just remove the vertical resistors for a moment and work out the voltages at each node. If you do that, you'll see that the voltages are identical from left to right. So inserting back the vertical resistors won't cause any current in them. So they may as well not be there.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implicit assumption: that we are only connecting at points A and B.

**The two circuits are not the same if you connect at X and Y** (and lots of other nodes).

Circuit 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1s0eI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuit 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTX2sm.png)</sup>

**If we're considering the only connections to be at A and B**, then it's easy to reduce circuit 1 into circuit 2.  As said in comments, you can start with circuit 2, easily see that a voltage applied across A and B will produce the same voltage at X as at Y.  And so as no current will flow, regardless of the resistance R4 so you can add whatever you like.

Circuit 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWS5Wc.png)</sup>

**Connected across A and B** you can see Circuit 3 is the same as the previous two.

Comment: I appreciate that you have thoroughly explained it with pictures. Thank you very much!

Comment: To add, it was not included in my post. But the terminal A and B has current source. Does it apply the same reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

By **symmetry** the voltages across the resistors which are omitted in the simplified circuit are zero, so the resistors can be removed without affecting the behavior at the terminals. No calculations are necessary.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate why would the voltage across the resistors be zero? Thank you for answering.

Comment: The symmetrical arrangement means the same voltage will be present on both sides. If any of the horizontal 3 ohm resistors were a different value the symmetry could be broken. Note that if the top triplet was 3-3-3 and the bottom was 2-2-2 it would still hold, but be a bit less obvious.

Comment: Imagine the vertical resistors are not there, the voltages with one side connected to ground and the other to V would be  (2/3)V and  (1/3)V on each side of the two resistors, so no current will flow, and the vertical resistors could be 0 or infinite ohms with no change.

Comment: I now get it, thanks for explaining! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is symmetry because of which voltage across nodes 1 and 3 and voltage difference between nodes 2 and 4 is zero. No current flows between them and the connections between nodes 1-3 and 2-4 become open circuits. Therefore, the resistors between nodes 1-3 and 2-4 can be removed.

Answer (score -1):

My initial thought is to take a look at the Δ-Y transform shown in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform). This assumes that there is additional circuitry that you haven't included in your original images. If you perform the appropriate transform operations on each edge, my guess is that you'll see the result you're expecting pretty quickly.

Comment: I agree that the Δ-Y transform could show this result, but the algebra is not trivial. I suspect that the blood stains on OP's diagram might be the result of such a battle.