# Why does the resistor connected in parallel in the middle not get any current?

Tags: resistors

[image]

The horizontal resistor in the middle does not get any current and it is also ignored when calculating the total circuit resistance which is:

[(1/(1+1))^-1 + (1/(1+1))^-1]^-1 = 1 kΩ

I don't understand why it gets 0 current.

Comment: Welcome!  Perhaps [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/639062) helps?

Comment: Which direction were you expecting current to flow in across it? Why?

Comment: By symmetry whatever current flows on the left leg also flows in the right leg so the voltage drops are the same.

Comment: Trying to explain to us why you think there should be current may trigger the realisation that there won't be 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Both ends of the resistor have identical voltage. As there is no voltage difference over a resistor there will be no current through it. It can be seen from Ohm's law.

Comment: so if the 2 vertical resistors on the top would have different resistances, there would be a voltage difference across the horizontal resistor giving it a current?

Comment: That's correct yes

Comment: Moreover, this particular property of the circuit in question is of importance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge

Comment: In practice, you'll have a _tiny_ current because the resistors will never be exactly balanced. Not much of a problem here with the high resistances, but something to keep in mind when you connect potentials that are _supposed_ to be ground ...

Answer (score 11):

This circuit involves a concept called the Wheatstone Bridge. You can read more about it [here](https://www.electronicshub.org/wheatstone-bridge/).
Basically, if $$\frac{R1}{R2} = \frac{R3}{R4}$$, the potential at points A and B will be equal. For current to flow, there must be some potential difference to drive it. However, since there is no potential difference between the points A and B, no current can flow between them. Hence, the resistor placed between the two points can be ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no voltage across it.

Answer (score 1):

current only flows when there's a potential difference (PD) across the element. If both ends of the element are at the same voltage, then no PD, therefore no current.